# Alter SQL FileTable Location From SQL Server Machine To Another Machine

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filestream, filetable

I want to run This Command To Replace Location of SQL FileTable from Local Location To Another Location In Another Machine

like That

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDb modify FILE (NAME='name', FILENAME=N'\\192.168.10.229\FolderName')
```

But I Get This ERROR

> "The path '\192.168.10.229\FolderName' cannot be used for FILESTREAM
>   files. For information about supported paths, see SQL Server Books
>   Online."

Comment: 1. Well for starters: "\ComputerName\FolderName" is invalid location. 2. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/01/sql-server-databases-on-network-shares-nas/

Comment: Alex This Work With mdf and ldf Files only, But With Filestream Not Work

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: Thank You Alex for This Important Article, I read It.